# Classroom Sign-Out/In

Tags: google-forms

I am a teacher trying to create a sign-out form (using forms so students can't edit the submitted data) for use in my school to track students going various places and the time for each. I piloted a version last year, which could take their information, have them choose where they were going and record the time, but have been trying to make signing back in automated and I simply cannot get it to happen without coding skills. While I have taught myself a bit of very basic things using Google's App Scripts (like how to insert a pop-up window) I am seriously struggling with the anything more than that. : (

Basically I have set up a Google form with the first step collecting student information (which is going to be done using a QR code to launch the Google form with some pre-filled data based on each student). The student then clicks from several options to choose where they are going (and it skips to sections based on answers). When they submit, the information populates in a Google sheet so we can use it for various purposes. I need to point out that I can't just have a straight in and out, as this needs to track students going to various teachers, the office, bathroom or to get water. The problem I am having is automating the sign back in process, as last year myself and another teacher that used it had to stop what we were doing to sign them back in and it became unrealistic. I was hoping someone could help me solve the issue in at least one of the following ways:

1. Upon submitting a response, add the submitted name to a popup window
   that becomes visible when anyone has the document open. The name
   could then be clicked like a button to record a second time as their
   sign-in time (since the sheet collects the first time as their sign
   out).
2. Similar to how it is done in [this Stackoverflow](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F24603794%2Fdynamically-fill-form-fields-based-on-other-responses-before-submit&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH46MK_KRfwq6qjcbH1tAHXa51nQw) post, instead of
   making a box, is it possible to have the form itself modify and when
   a student submits, it adds their name to a part of the form
   sectioned as "signed-out" and when they submit an answer from that
   section, it is then removed? This is similar to a script called
   "[CheckItOut](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fedlistenscripts%2Fcheckitout&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGI44skY12m4A6chyS8ot0wAf_tOQ)", but doesn't require to input 650 names and 50
   categories.
3. Instead of modifying the form itself, can we set up a
   formula in the response sheet using ifs, arrays, querys or whatever
   else to match a person who signs out, with their sign back in time?
   (The obvious problem being that the sign back in order will not
   match the sign out order as [addressed here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/nWwJ2F5aW0g/oRzpLgaLAQAJ).) From there I should be
   able to just make it do the math to find the differences between the
   sign-out and in times.

Any help would be immensely appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hey Mr. Frat,  This seems like a pretty cool project.  Is this tracking being done on the student's mobile device?  Would you have the ability to enable any proximity tracking sensors?

Comment: While it is a really cool thought, sadly we can't use the tracking sensors. Students can sign out using theirs phones, but will most likely use a classroom Chromebook.

Comment: So everything is entered in a Google Form then?  I don't see a good way to automate anything there other than perhaps a simple check-in timestamp button...  It will still require a person to hit the in button, and associating the correct in time with the correct out record.

Comment: Would it be beneficial to have a proactive reminder if someone isn't back in a certain amount of time?  That's something you probably could automatize...

Comment: Google Forms will actually automatically collect a time and date stamp any time the form is submitted, but the problem is trying to match the time with with the time back in. While a reminder that someone is still out at the end of the day would be good, I feel like it would be better to just cut the time off at the end of the school day so it doesn't keep counting and the next time the sign out with will match up the out and in time again.